# Is there a way to capture keypress from a Button with Urwid?

Tags: python, urwid

I'm using a Urwid button and wonder if there's a way to handle keypress events directly on the button?

```
urwid.Button((item["customer"] + "/ " + item["case"]), button_press_pick_case,
                                             user_data=item)
```

I know I can probably do this by capturing MainLoop's `unhandled_input` and then finding the currently focused button, but I wonder if there's an easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for global shortcuts, the way to go is really the `unhandled_input`.

If you want to make the button to answer to an additional key combination, you can edit the button's [`CommandMap`](http://urwid.org/reference/command_map.html#urwid.CommandMap), which is accessible through [the `_command_map` widget attribute](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Widget._command_map), but it will only work when the button has the focus.